# What is the purpose of the Flux Dispatcher (vs. simply having instance methods)

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am trying to understand the purpose of the flux dispatcher.

Here is a simple example (taken from http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/)

```
// Single object representing list data and logic
var ListStore = {

    // Actual collection of model data
    items: []

};

// Tell the dispatcher we want to listen for *any*
// dispatched events

MicroEvent.mixin( ListStore );

AppDispatcher.register( function( payload ) {

    switch( payload.actionName ) {

        // Do we know how to handle this action?
        case 'new-item':

            // We get to mutate data!
            ListStore.items.push( payload.newItem );
            // Tell the world we changed!
            ListStore.trigger( 'change' );
            break;

    }

}); 

ListActions = {

    add: function( item ) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            eventName: 'new-item',
            newItem: item
        });
    }

};
```

```

It would seem at the end of the day I am going to simply say

```
ListActions.add(12)
```

So what purpose does having a dispatcher, and then creating the `add` action-creator serve (besides wearing out my keyboard?)

Even in a large project I am not sure where this pattern does anything but make me type a lot more.

Comment: One answer possibly is that it allows multiple "stores" to respond to a single action without the entity raising the action knowing that multiple stores care.  Is this the answer?

Answer (score 0):

found a good explanation here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html